# Diagnosis on thumping noise from the front

Tags: suspension, noise, opel

I need a bit of help on diagnosing the source of a rumbling noise.

For several weeks I hear a rumble (one or two thumping's) from the front of my car when I do a sharp right turn (90°) in moderate velocity (at least 30 Km/h).

- There are no suspicious sounds when doing a left turn.
- The noise happens only once/perhaps twice when I start the turn, not while turning. I can make several full turns on an even parking space without additional noises
- I think (unsure) the noise becomes more audible when the road is uneven/inclined.
- I think (unsure) that the sound originates from the front left area.
- Two months ago the car was in a workshop for gearbox repairs, perhaps some component was damaged there or mounted incorrectly (the entire engine carrier was removed).
- I am unsure if the sound developed gradually or of a sudden
- There are no unusual sounds when I hit the brakes or accelerate
- When driving on a rough dirt-road I think that I hear the noise, but I am unsure because background noises overlap.
- Since the noise only happens when doing a sharp turn, most of the time on uneven/inclined roads, I cannot judge if the car behaves differently.

**Some informations about the car**

It is a 2009 Opel Astra H Caravan with about 140 KKm. It is a FWD, manual transmission.
It has an ordinary McPherson-suspension.
The front shock absorbers are becoming weak, I hear them them every day when I need to move over an higher-than-average obstacle on my driveway. I don't know if that's part of the problem. I plan to replace them after the winter.

The following link illustrates the control arm. [Link](http://ecat24.com/opel/catalog/part/1/9/402/4333/1166,1168/)

I also have a illustration of the suspension
[image]

Both stabilizer links got replaced by me because the seals where ruptured (one before the gearbox repair, one after).

When I changed the wheels two weeks ago there was no feel-able play on the wheel/stabilizer links/control arm/steering knuckle. 
I am a bit unsure of those results because I did not use a crowbar/similar tool to check the control arm and the stabilizer links where under tension because I was using a single car jack to raise the vehicle.

I am inclined to think that ball joint on the control arm is worn, perhaps somebody could point out other candidates or checks?

Comment: So the noise started after you had it in the workshop for gearbox repairs? What are the condition of the struts?

Comment: @CharlieRB Yes, it started after I had the car in the shop. The struts are becoming weak, I want to replace them next year. No liquid visible..

Comment: It has probably been too long to take it back to the shop. The reason I asked about the struts is the bearing on top of the strut can wear to the point of making all sorts of sounds through the body when the strut moves and twists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If somebody is interested: The noise came from the supports of the stabilizer bar which went loose.

Answer (score 2):

Could be a outer CV joint beginning to go. You mentioned the on the right hand side during a sharp right turn.

Comment: The sound appears just on the start of the turn. While turning there are no sounds

Comment: @myself - I did say it was beginning to go. If it is the CV as it progresses it will get worse.